# Python flattening json to long, not wide - with nested lists and nested jsons

Tags: python, json, list, nested, flatten

I've tried flattening with pandas  `df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(data[key]) for key in data.keys()])`
but get a single row of wide data.
I need long data while preserving the values of some higher levels against the rows of each set of flattened nested list or nested json.

I tried pandas pd.concat and got a table but the nested lists and nested json remain unflattened jsons or lists in each cell.  Grateful for solution or even just a clear approach.

Desired output columns for the output table with 3 rows of sample data from the json input in the code block at the bottom:

| timeseries_stat.id | timeseries_stat.start_time | timeseries_stat.end_time | ad.id | timeseries.start_time | timeseries.end_time | impressions | swipes | quartile_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61dd994300ff07c... | 2021-12-10T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 2021-17-10T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 7d0725b5-4fae-... | 2021-12-10T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 2021-12-11T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 37442 | 130 | 32244 |
| 61dd994300ff07c... | 2021-12-10T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 2021-17-10T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 7d0725b5-4fae-... | 2021-12-11T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 2021-12-12T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 48740 | 209 | 42394 |
| 61dd994300ff07c... | 2021-12-10T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 2021-17-10T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 7d0725b5-4fae-... | 2021-12-12T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 2021-12-13T00:00:00.000-05:00 | 49593 | 198 | 43067 |

Json input data is below.

```
"{"request_id":"61dd994300ff07c7614f4809360001737e616473617069736300016275696c642d62663862383439622d312d3530382d300001014a","timeseries_stats":[{"timeseries_stat":{"id":"f0b0c3e6-eabd-4103-b260-0336b7d86644","start_time":"2021-12-10T00:00:00.000-05:00","end_time":"2021-12-17T00:00:00.000-05:00","breakdown_stats":{"ad":[{"id":"7d0725b5-4fae-4ac8-ba54-fb8bd82e4a9c","timeseries":[{"start_time":"2021-12-10T00:00:00.000-05:00","end_time":"2021-12-11T00:00:00.000-05:00","stats":{"impressions":37442,"swipes":130,"quartile_1":32244}},{"start_time":"2021-12-11T00:00:00.000-05:00","end_time":"2021-12-12T00:00:00.000-05:00","stats":{"impressions":48740,"swipes":209,"quartile_1":42394}},{"start_time":"2021-12-12T00:00:00.000-05:00","end_time":"2021-12-13T00:00:00.000-05:00","stats":{"impressions":49593,"swipes":198,"quartile_1":43067}}]},{"id":"b5a066d9-4aa1-49ea-b732-12c5f54aff15","timeseries":[{"start_time":"2021-12-10T00:00:00.000-05:00","end_time":"2021-12-11T00:00:00.000-05:00","stats":{"impressions":118510,"swipes":581,"quartile_1":101248}}]}]}]}}}]}
```

Comment: We can't help you produce your desired output without knowing what the input looks like.

Comment: The input data is all there but the person who kindly edited accidentally merged the desired columns with the input data. Please see above. I'll try to edit again to make it clearer and wait for someone to approve edits.  Thanks, @TimRoberts for noticing it wasn't clear.

Comment: I went through the dataset and I would recommend pre-processing the JSON string and projecting out the required keys to a newer list of dictionaries. You can then pass the list of dictionaries to `pandas.DataFrame()` to get the desired Dataframe

Comment: Do we need this many columns, this much data, metadata like the `"request_id"` etc. in order to reproduce the problem? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and try to create a small input that demonstrates the problem, along with corresponding desired and actual output.

Comment: Thanks for helpful comments, @KarlKnechtel . I've cut down the input to minimum to show structure. Although 'request id' is not needed in the output, it is part of the input data structure that needs to be handled so I didn't want to leave it out accidentally. I'm fairly new to Python and json wrangling.

Comment: @YayatiSule if I populate a list with dictionaries of key 'stats' (for example) then how do I ensure each of these lists stays together with the correct timeseries start and end times (next level out) and the correct ad id (next level out) and timeseries_stat start and end dates (outer level)?  Won't I end up with a list of dictionaries for 'stats' that is missing the parent info?  Is your proposed idea to iterate the json and write key-values for parent data into each 'stats' list as I go?